# Check if intrinsic module constant is defined

Tags: fortran, preprocessor, built-in

The Fortran standard evolves and as new intrinsic variables are introduced, compilers pick those up after a while. One example is the variable `C_PTRDIFF_T`.

To make my code compilable with older compilers as well, I'd like to define intrinsic variables if they are not already defined by the compiler itself, e.g,

```
program test
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  Integer, Parameter :: C_PTRDIFF_T = 12
end program
```

How can I make this portable across compilers?

Answer (score 3):

Try and compile and run something akin to:

```
USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING, ONLY: C_PTRDIFF_T
IF (C_PTRDIFF_T >= 0) THEN
  PRINT "('Ok')"
ELSE
  PRINT "('Not ok')"
END IF
END
```

If compilation suceeds, the compiler is aware of the standard that supports C_PTRDIFF_T.

If running the program then prints Ok (so the value of C_PTRDIFF_T constant is non-negative), the processor also supports an integer that is interoperable with the relevant C type.

Based on this test you can then configure your program proper as appropriate, perhaps by selecting slightly different source code for a module that either provides a stand-alone definition of or forwards C_PTRDIFF_T from ISO_C_BINDING.

The ability for later standards to add new entities to the intrinsic modules is why a programming style that always uses an ONLY clause on USE statements for intrinsic modules is sometimes recommended.

(Note C_PTRDIFF_T is a constant in an intrinsic module, it is not a variable nor intrinsic.)

Comment: Making the code fail if the variable isn't defined is easy. I'm looking for a way to support all compilers from the same code base though. I clarified this in the original post.

Comment: From final "true" Fortran source - you can't.  You have to change the final Fortran source in some way.  Depending on your build environment you could select alternative source files as described in the answer (perhaps the little test program writes the actual intermediate module - that's something you often see for kind selection), or maybe use the preprocessor.  The other obvious answer is to not use C_PTRDIFF_T from ISO_C_BINDING until all your compilers support that future standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this within a procedure because USE association trumps host association:

```
module goodstuf
   implicit none
   interface f
      module procedure f4, f8
   end interface f
   contains
      function f4(x)
         integer(4) f4
         integer(4), intent(in) :: x
         f4 = x**2+1
      end function f4
      function f8(x)
         integer(8) f8
         integer(8), intent(in) :: x
         f8 = x**3-1
      end function f8
end module goodstuf

module user5713492_C_BINDING
   implicit none
!   integer, parameter :: C_PTRDIFF_T = 8
end module user5713492_C_BINDING

module anymod
   use goodstuf
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: C_PTRDIFF_T = 4
   contains
      subroutine sub
         use user5713492_C_BINDING
         integer(C_PTRDIFF_T) x
         x = 7
         write(*,*) f(x)
      end subroutine sub
end module anymod

program main
   use anymod
   implicit none
   call sub
end program main
```

This prints out `50` when the definition of `C_PTRDIFF_T` is commented out in module `user5713492_C_BINDING` and `342` when it is in effect. But what I was hoping to do was to define a named constant that had the value `1` when `C_PTRDIFF_T` was define and `0` when not. I could achieve this for the named constant `test` via the `STORAGE_SIZE`, `BIT_SIZE`, and `DIM` intrinsics using implicit typing assuming the `KIND` of a default integer was not `INT8`. But then to squash `C_PTRDIFF_T` when it's not defined seems to require a compiler bug of some sort. I tried this with gfortran and turned up a couple of bugs, and finally one that allowed this to work, squashing the `FSOURCE=` argument to the `MERGE` intrinsic. It didn't work with ifort, unfortunately.

```
module goodstuf
   implicit none
   interface f
      module procedure f4, f8
   end interface f
   contains
      function f4(x)
         integer(4) f4
         integer(4), intent(in) :: x
         f4 = x**2+1
      end function f4
      function f8(x)
         integer(8) f8
         integer(8), intent(in) :: x
         f8 = x**3-1
      end function f8
end module goodstuf

module user5713492_C_BINDING
   implicit none
!   integer, parameter :: C_PTRDIFF_T = 8
end module user5713492_C_BINDING

module filter
   use user5713492_C_BINDING
   use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV, only: INT8
   implicit integer(INT8) (C)
   integer, parameter :: PTRDIFF_size = storage_size(C_PTRDIFF_T)
   integer, parameter :: test = dim(1,(PTRDIFF_size-bit_size(1))**2)
   integer, parameter :: MY_PTRDIFF_T = 4
! First test: try to squash PAD= argument to RESHAPE
!   integer, parameter :: array1(test) = reshape([integer(INT8)::],[test],pad=[C_PTRDIFF_T])
!   integer, parameter :: array2(1) = reshape(array1,[1],pad=[MY_PTRDIFF_T])
! Second test: try to squash assignment to zero-length array
!   integer, parameter :: array1(test) = C_PTRDIFF_T
!   integer, parameter :: array2(1) = reshape(array1,[1],pad=[MY_PTRDIFF_T])
! Third test: try to squash zero-length structure constructor
! Fails with gfortran with C_PTRDIFF_T defined. Bug?
!   type T
!      integer array(test)
!   end type T
!   type(T), parameter :: T1 = T(C_PTRDIFF_T)
!   integer, parameter :: array2(1) = reshape(T1%array,[1],pad=[MY_PTRDIFF_T])
! Fourth test: try to squash BOUNDARY= argument to EOSHIFT
! gfortan gives misleading error message with C_PTRDIFF_T undefined.
!   integer, parameter :: array2(1) = eoshift([integer(KIND(C_PTRDIFF_T))::MY_PTRDIFF_T],1,boundary=C_PTRDIFF_T)
! Fifth test: try to squash FSOURCE= argument to MERGE
!!! WORKS WITH gfortran!!!
   integer, parameter :: array2(1) = merge([integer(KIND(C_PTRDIFF_T))::MY_PTRDIFF_T],C_PTRDIFF_T,test==0)
   integer, parameter :: OK_PTRDIFF_T = array2(1)
end module filter

program main
   use goodstuf
   use filter
   implicit none
   integer(OK_PTRDIFF_T) x
   x = 7
   write(*,*) f(x)
end program main
```